# How to create a custom Session Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

Requirement:

We need to store high-volume user session data in Spring boot for one of my projects using a session repository.

I have tried Redis as an option but unfortunately, it got failed in a clustered environment.

We want to store the non-persistence session in a clustered environment using a session repository.

Highly appreciated it if someone can share the peace of code or the git repo sample code. Please help.